# Can I get ScriptNames for a file through the FileMaker data API?

Tags: api, filemaker

I need to get a list of scripts for a database file through the FileMaker 17 data API.

I've tried looking in the documentation.

I'm looking for something similar to this, available in the PHP API.

`ScriptNames(fileName)`

I want to get a list of all scripts on a file.

Comment: This is a perfectly good question, and should not have been down-voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, not in FileMaker 17. In FileMaker 18 there is an endpoint:

```
/fmi/data/version/databases/database-name/scripts
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you!  I will push for an upgrade here at work!

Answer (score 3):

Not according to the docs. 
Your best bet could be to have an utility script that you call with the desired function as a parameter and then execute the utility script as part of a Create Record command.

You should have a log/transaction table to create records to keep track of requests and results in separate fields. The newly created record object will be returned and will include the result of the function.

Comment: I'm not interested in doing _more_ work... but this could be a useful approach for someone else.  As noted in question, I checked the documentation.

Comment: Ok, but this is quite simple to implement and will give you what you want as well as a universal way to query the database about anything. Logging is useful also for a number of reasons.